# user in sudo group can't run sudo

Tags: sudo, visudo

I've seen other similar questions but they don't solve my problem unfortunately.

I've been added to the sudo group on my Ubuntu 14.04 with

```
usermod -aG sudo testuser
```

but I still can't run sudo:

```
 :~$ groups
     testuser sudo
 :~$ sudo -s
     testuser is not allowed to run sudo ...
```

I can't add:

```
testuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to the /etc/sudoers.
I've tried also:

```
 sg sudo
```

I've tried to logout and login again into the machine.
Do you have any ideas?

I don't have sudo access and so I can't run:

```
sudo grep sudo /etc/sudoers | grep -v "#"
```

but I saw before that the line with

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

is not commented out.

### SOLUTION

At the end was just a problem of administration. The admin had to give me the sudo access for that machine inside another setting (I don't know how and not with usermod) also if I was already inside the sudo group, now it works. Thanks all.

Comment: Please `edit` your question and post the output of `sudo grep sudo /etc/sudoers | grep -v "#"`

Comment: That solution isn't really a solution. There's no detail about what needed to be done to fix the issue.